# What is the correct pronunciation of 'Ubuntu'?

Tags: community, history-of-ubuntu

I have never been good at deciphering the pronunciation guides:

> ubuntu |oǒ'boǒntoō|

What is the best way to describe the pronunciation with like sounding words for each syllable?

**"oǒ"**: ?

**"boǒn"**: like Boone as in Daniel or like bun as in hamburger?

**"toō"**: like too as in also?

Comment: I always pronounced it You-bahn-chew, but apperantly I am wrong. I once heard someone say Oo-bun-too, I thought it sounded funny, but based on the other answers he was closer than I was.

Comment: I agree with Buyongo's proposal. He is correct. Proper pronunciation should be maintained. In many parts of India Ubuntu is pronounced as "oo-bun-tu". here the 't' is pronounced in a different but soft and slippery-smooth way.

Comment: It's pronounced "jif", as all things are.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's Nelson Mandela ...  [Short clip : The Meaning of Ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UT-3Eh65kkA) .

Actually, you get the interviewer pronouncing *Ubuntu* twice,  and you'll hear Mandela pronounce *Ubuntu* near the end of the clip.

To attempt a quick summary, the *bun* is close to *Boone* in *Daniel Boone* or `\bün\` ;

and *tu* is close to *too*, or `\tü\` .   The initial *u* matches this sound.

Comment: Still a lot of (Ubuntu) developers out there calling it Oo-buhn-too!  Hmmm....  Buns...  I also hear a fair bit of "You-buhn-too" or "You-boon-too".  Jorge nails it here : http://castrojo.blip.tv/file/4998464/

Comment: What, Jorge pronounces his own name "George" and not spanish [ˈxoɾxe]?

Comment: I should point out that my South African friends are unanimous in using Mandela's pronunciation. Saying Oo-buhn-too would result in a quick pronunciation lesson. It seems that Zulu and Xhosa (the source languages for Ubuntu) pronunciation is fairly straightforward except for the clicks.

Comment: Spanish users need not to worry about it since Ubuntu is pronounce exactly as it should (And as Nelson Mandela pronounce's it). Both U are pronounced like the sound of a double O. Like in the final Doo in Scooby Dooby Doo. That is how the U is pronounced.

Comment: @CYREX I have to say, I really like Scooby Dooby Doo as an Ubuntu pronunciation mnemonic.

Answer (score 14):

ou.boon.too = ubuntu

In most languages from southern Africa, *ubuntu* = humanity to others, *bantu* = people.

In some languages the "b" is pronunced as a "w", for instance my name "Buyongo" is pronunced "Wuyongo". A westerner will make the mistake of saying buy.on.go, which is incorrect. Another example is Busisiwe which is said Wusisiwe even though it has the letter B.

So if you used a genuine southern African accent to pronunce it, it would sound more like ou.woon.tu, but for simplicity sake lets just say ou.boon.too.  It's the popular way anyhow. :)

Answer (score 6):

[How To Pronounce Ubuntu - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fJF5UIS_hE)

> pronunciationbook
>
> Published on 11 Sep 2010
>
> This video shows you how to say Ubuntu. Learn the correct American English pronunciation of the Linux distribution.

Comment: Yeah. Not sure this is it though. That sound file sounds very "English" to me. Ubuntu is an African word. The real answer for me is "I don't know". But my gut feeling is that the 'u' is more like 'oo' in 'good', like the French 'ou' or the German/Scandinavian 'u'.

Comment: To me, this pronunciation is close to what I hear in the Mandela clip.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very short clip from an interview with another very famous person demonstrating the **correct pronunciation of Ubuntu :-)**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGox0EKqiaE

Comment: unavailable, then again 2013 vs 2018... I suspect it doesn't matter any more

Comment: Thanks, I think I accidentally deleted that short video clip I had uploaded, so I'll just cite another one that I can't delete ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### Official

From the Wikipedia page on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu):

> ([/ʊˈbʊntuː/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) ([listen](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/En-Ubuntu_pronunciation.oga)) [*uu-BUUN-too*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pronunciation_respelling_key))<sup>[[1]](https://www.ubuntu.com/about)</sup>

This is written in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) followed by Wikipedia's English respelling system.

- The vowels are /ʊ/ *uu* as in FOOT and /uː/ *oo* as in GOOSE.
- The consonants /b, n, t/ are pronounced as they're written.
- The second syllable is emphasized.
- The colon-like symbol after /u/ is just a length marker, which isn't very important in English.

The citation here is the official [About Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/about) page, where the pronunciation is written `|oǒ'boǒntoō|`. I'm not sure what system that's written in, but it might be a variant of the pre-IPA Oxford system, described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English#Traditional_respelling_systems) under the "POD" column.

### Unofficial

Another pronunciation I've heard in North American English is /uˈbʌntu/ *oo-BUN-too*, with /ʌ/ as in STRUT. Another is /juˈbʌntu/ *you-BUN-too*, with the first syllable /ju/ = "you", which is arguably incorrect. The second syllable is emphasized in both of these.

### Zulu

While we're here, it's worth mentioning that the word "ubuntu" originally comes from the Bantu languages (e.g. Xhosa, Zulu). I've never heard this used to refer to the OS, but for context, Wikipedia has the Zulu pronunciation on the page [Ubuntu philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_philosophy):

> [[ùɓúntʼù]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Zulu)<sup>[[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wZtfqZ271w#t=162)</sup><sup>[[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftjdDOfTzbk)</sup>

This is way more complicated for an English speaker. The accents indicate tones, the /ɓ/ is an implosive, and the /tʼ/ is an ejective.

Comment: Listening to audio clip: Ewbuntu would be phonetic spelling?

Comment: @Win No, the first and second vowels are the same.

Comment: LOL I give up. I've always pronounced it YOU-BUN-TWO in my head. Since I don't know anyone that will say "Ubuntu" nor anyone that I would say "Ubuntu" to, official pronunciation is irrelevant :).

Comment: @Win Haha, fair point :) If it helps, your pronunciation is probably /ju'bʌntu/ or *you-BUN-too* in [Wikipedia's respelling system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pronunciation_respelling_key). The official pronunciation, /ʊˈbʊntuː/, would be respelled *uu-BUUN-too*. Oh also the colon after /u/ indicates length, which isn't applicable for (most) North American accents.