# Why doesn't Ubuntu know the word 'Ubuntu'?

Tags: dictionary, naming

It seems odd that I have to teach Ubuntu the word 'Ubuntu'. Why doesn't it know itself. Are there any plans to fix this?

It's been like this for as long as I can remember. I'm currently on 10.10.

Question inspired by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34980/how-do-you-pronounce-ubuntu).

Comment: I agree to put on the dictionary. but most us are using Google definition  http://www.google.com.et/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3Aubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a good idea, previously raised in [this Brainstorm idea](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714090732/http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/24718/).  I don't know of any reason why it's not there; it just needs someone to make the change.

[Bug 63499](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hunspell/+bug/63499) asks for this to be done.  Ubuntu ships multiple dictionaries (even for English) so it may need updates to multiple packages.

Comment: Ah, didn't know it was already 'brainstormed'. I'll be happy to file that bug if someone let's me know which package to do so against.

Comment: @boehj, I found it, see above.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at this.